Call to undefined function PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\simplexml_load_string()
I’m working with PhpSpreadsheet to upload and process CSV files. However, when I submit the form to upload a CSV, I receive this error:
Call to undefined function PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\simplexml_load_string()
I’ve already tried the following steps but none have resolved the issue:

Installed the php-xml extension using the command:
sudo apt-get install php-xml

Un-commented the extension=xml line in my php.ini file.

Cleared the PHP cache by restarting the web server (Apache/Nginx) using:
sudo systemctl restart apache2 (for Apache) or
sudo systemctl restart nginx (for Nginx)

Verified the XML extension is enabled by running:
php -m | grep xml


But the issue persists. Could anyone suggest other steps or insights to resolve this error? I’m using PHP version 8.3 in ubuntu csv file is uploaded but while i am uploading xlsx format this error occurs

Not sure what you'd think php-xml would have to do with this. simplexml_load_string is a function provided by the SimpleXML extension. This sounds rather like you have some namespace conflict, so that it tries to locate a method of that name in the class PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader instead.
